React table with lazy loading that display the whole table height initially
I am using react-table v8 and I would like to enhance our tables performance as our cells are a little bit complex and we receive thousands of data. Therefore, I think it's time to switch from client side handeling of data to the server side.
So I have some requirements to implement the Lazy Loading:

First, it has to be lazy loading not pagination as we don't have the concept of pages in our App
We need to fetch data as the user scrolls down
The table height should be initially displayed without a 'load more' button or loading text.
The user should be able to navigate freely in the table using the mouse or keyboard. For example, pressing the 'End' button should scroll to the latest data. (not the displayed row)


I haven't found a good example that explains how to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have many questions such as :
Should I use the infinite query of the react query ? As it is shown in the docs in this example of react table lazy loading ? As you see, there is no next page concept in my use case since it is a huge long table and the user can scroll freely using the scrollbar.
What if the user scrolls to the end of the page? How do I tell React Table which rows should be displayed initially and which ones should be displayed at the end?
Should I use the pagination options of React Table, or I implement something else myself?
As I have many feature to implement later such as the selection, the sorting, the filter ... I need to implement this feature the right way.
Any ideas?

You should introduce yourself to windowing.
General idea is that you want to display full content of the rows in viewport. Optionally, if you want to maintain Ctrl+F functionality, only shallow, text representation of cells out of viewport. As a rule of thumb, remember, the less DOM nodes you display, the better performance.
Example pseudocode:
const { from, to } = useRowsBatchRenderer(bodyRef);

return (
  <>
    {rows.map((row) =>
      row.index < from || row.index > to ? (
        // if row is out of viewport, only render its text representation, without wrapping with CPU-expensive DOM nodes
        <ShallowGridRow
          key={row.index}
          row={row}
          height={getRowHeight(row.index) ?? minRowHeight} // For smooth scroll experience, you may also want to remember the rendered row height. If row is nit yet rendered, and height is unknown, set it to some static value
        />
      ) : (
        <GridRow key={row.index} row={row} />
      )
    )}
  </>
);

export function useRowsBatchRenderer(body: RefObject<HTMLTableSectionElement>) {
  const [rowIndicesToRender, setRowIndicesToRender] = useState<Extremes>({
    from: 0,
    to: 0,
  });

  const calculateRowIndicesToRender = useCallback(() => {
    const { scrollY, innerHeight } = window;
    // Placeholder for your custom implementation. Calculate basing on window dimensions, and table body measurements 
    setRowIndicesToRender({from: 0, to: 10});
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const throttledRerender = throttle(
      (_: Event) => calculateRowIndicesToRender(),
      50
    );

    window.addEventListener("resize", throttledRerender);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", throttledRerender);

    return () => {
      throttledRerender.cancel();
      window.removeEventListener("resize", throttledRerender);
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", throttledRerender);
    };
  }, [calculateRowIndicesToRender]);

  return rowIndicesToRender;
}

export function ShallowGridRow<D>({ height, row }: ShallowRowProps<D>) {
  // `shallowData` - delimit values with special character of your choice, NOT a white space
// NOTE: single cell per row, the less DOM nodes the better
  return (
    <tr style={{ height, overflow: "hidden", color: "transparent", wordBreak: "break-word" }}>
      <td>{row.shallowData}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export function GridRow<D>({ row }: RowProps<D>) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {visibleColumns.map((column) => (
        <td key={column.id}>
          <VERY_EXPENSIVE_CELL_RENDERER row={row} />
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
}


I am using react-window actually, and I want to keep it AND receive only a part of the data that I pass to the react table model. Instead of passing everything. So instead of the ShallowGridRow, I display a LoadingRow. Whenever the LoadingRow is visible in the viewport, my component fetch new data from the server based on how many row I want to display. The thing is, I feel like I am writing my own logic and I am not using react table pagination feature much in my use case. BTW, the sorting, filter ... will pas through the server as well.
